# Azure Data Factory Pagination - get next page with AbsoluteURL

Tags: pagination, azure-data-factory

I am trying to get the next page from API response, I have already tried using "AbsouteURL" which seems to "work" as it tries to call that URL (I can see that in the ADF output log).

The issue seems to be the response not having correct url in the response, it just says 0.0.0.0 instead of actual URL.

example:

"meta": {
"count": 500,
"pageCount": 10,
"totalCount": 50000,
"next": "http://0.0.0.0:3000/myData/myDataId?page=2&limit=25",
"previous": null,
"self": "http://0.0.0.0:3000/myData/myDataId?page=1&limit=25",
"first": "http://0.0.0.0:3000/myData/myDataId?page=1&limit=25",
"last": "http://0.0.0.0:3000/myData/myDataId?page=400&limit=25"
},

Is is possible to replace "0.0.0.0" with actual host name i.e. 'myWebApplication' when passing using "AbsouteURL" property?

[image]

Comment: [how to perform pagination in azure data factory using Rest API? - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/236150/how-to-perform-pagination-in-azure-data-factory-us.html) and [Pagination in Azure data Factory(By REST API) (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/88d07711-2548-4031-bcff-f7252c72572f/pagination-in-azure-data-factoryby-rest-api) Check if this link help.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but in my case the "next" link is set to "http://0.0.0.****" instead of "http://myWebApplication***" due to which it does not work.